How to show the submenu for nebular in popover box when the menuBar is collapsed form?
I have the requirement for UI side in nebular theme as per the requirement. On the nebular menu_item expand section I am able to show the sub-menu using the children[]. But at the time of collapse form of menu_item side bar I need to show the subMenu in pop_over form. Without triggering the main Menu_items.
export const menuItems : NbMenuItem[] | any = [
{
    title: 'Dashboard',
    icon: { icon: 'dashboard', pack: 'icons' },
    link: '/dashboard',
    home: false,
}

 {
    title: 'Card-Menu',
    icon: { icon: 'booking', pack: 'icons' },
    link: '/cardMenu',
    home: true,
  },

{
    title: 'Manage Card',
    icon: { icon: 'Manage -icon', pack: 'icons' },
    autoCollapse:true,
    button: 'cardButton',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'ABC',
        link: '/ABC',
      
      },
      {
        title: 'xyz',
        link: '/xyz',
        
      },
]

